# How to save list items added to "Favorites" so that after closing the application they are not reset?

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlin. I have a feature in my application to add list items to "Favorites". As long as the application is open, items remain in Favorites. But as soon as I close it, the list of favorite items is reset to zero.

How can I make my favorite list items persist after the application closes?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var data = Data.initData()

    private val adapter by lazy {
        MainAdapter(data, { item ->
            navigateToDetail(item)
        }, { index ->
            swapData(index)
       }, true)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.app_name)
        initList()
    }

    // list initialization on the main screen
    private fun initList() {
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_main)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    // when clicking on "Add to favorites" you need to change isFavorite in a certain element of the list and notify the adapter about it
    private fun swapData(index: Int) {
        val itemClickedId = data[index].id
        val itemInList = data.first { data -> data.id == itemClickedId }
        itemInList.isFavorite = !itemInList.isFavorite
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(index)
    }
```

Partial list code

```
package com.app.appfirst

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Data(
    val id: Int,
    val fullWay: String,
    var isFavorite: Boolean,
    val detail: List<Detail>
): Parcelable {
    companion object {
        fun initData() =
            arrayListOf(
                Data(1,
                    "Moscow",
                    false,
                    arrayListOf(
                        Detail(
```

Comment: Save the data in a file, such as a SQLite database.

Comment: You're going to want to use the Android Persistence API: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage